# CSS/HTML to create two side-by-side, equal-width, collapsible columns, which retain column width after expanding, using grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is my first question here, as I am a newbie, so I hope I can explain what I need...

I am trying to create two collapsible "buttons" side-by-side (each taking up about half the width of the screen), which, when clicked, expand to reveal an equally-wide column of text (each column taking up about half the screen width). (FYI, the content within each column is code.) I am using CSS grid and HTML only (although I am open to using flexbox, of it makes more sense in this context.) This two-column format will repeat further down the page numerous times.

As I have it styled now, my buttons are not the correct width, and when clicked, their respective content does not behave (it expands to fill up the entire width of the screen and then wraps, I think).

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.code {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.code-buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1;
}

.collapsible[name="css_button"] {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.collapsible[name="html_button"] {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="code-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="collapsible" name="css_button">Media Object CSS</button>
  <pre class="code">
           <code id="media_objects_css">
        <!-- Expanded Column Content -->
           </code>
         </pre>

  <button type="button" class="collapsible" name="html_button">Media Object HTML</button>
  <pre class="code">
          <code id="media_objects_html">
       <!-- Expanded Column Content -->
          </code>
        </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, the first step in creating a flexbox layout is to use `display: flex`, not `display: grid`... The rest can be found among many tutorials. I'm partial to [MDN's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout). I suggest wrapping each `button`/`pre` pair with a `div`; it will be much easier to think about axes that way.

Comment: edited. Thanks. I meant "grid."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, it's just that your grid area was expecting only two elements as its immediate children, whereas you have 4 elements as the immediate children (the button and the pre tags). I've placed your two buttons and its respective pre tag within their own div tags, allowing for only 2 immediate children in your grid:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.code {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.code-buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1;
}

.collapsible[name="css_button"] {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.collapsible[name="html_button"] {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="code-buttons">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible" name="css_button">Media Object CSS</button>
    <pre class="code">
           <code id="media_objects_css">
        <!-- Expanded Column Content -->
           </code>
         </pre>

  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible" name="html_button">Media Object HTML</button>
    <pre class="code">
          <code id="media_objects_html">
       <!-- Expanded Column Content -->
          </code>
        </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! This was exactly the answer I needed!